# How can strategic oscillation be modified so that it only takes into account certain scoring level in it's criteria?

Tags: optaplanner

I am using bendable scoring in my project and i have multiple levels.

The criteria behind strategic oscillation has proved itself to be quite useful for the last two levels. So a move that breaks some constraints from level N-1 but improves some constraints from level N is really good.This helps the solver to escape from local optimum and the moves that follow after this one repair the broken constraints from level N-1 and produce a new best score.

While it is really useful between the last two levels it creates a mess when it starts allowing moves that improve a lower level but for example violate level 0.

So my question is can strategic oscillation be configured so it looks only at the last two levels, does OptaPlanner have this built-in? If not how can i make this possible, i guess i would have to implement a custom forager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'd want to create a custom `FinalistPodium` which is used inside the `Forager`. Just like an Olympic podium, it says who's number 1, who's number 2 and so forth.

See `StrategicOscillationByLevelFinalistPodium.java`. Here be dragons. This is very internal code, not public API. You might not want to do this.

As for getting your own plugged in, overwrite `LocalSearchForagerConfig.buildForager()` in your own `ForagerConfig` and plug it in through the programmatic API (`SolverConfig` etc).

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey i will see what i can do.